# How to compare a local CLOB column against a CLOB column in a remote database instance

Tags: oracle, compare, clob

I want to verify that the data in 2 CLOB columns is the same on 2 different instances. If these were VARCHAR2 columns, I could use a MINUS or a join to determine if rows were in one instance or the other. Unfortunately, Oracle does not allow you to perform set operations on CLOB columns.

**How do I compare 2 CLOB columns, one of which is in my local instance and one that is in a remote instance?**

Example table structure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE X.TEXT_TABLE
(   ID VARCHAR2,
  NAME VARCHAR2,
  TEXT CLOB
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use an Oracle global temporary table to pull the CLOBs over to your local instance temporarily. You can then use the DBMS_LOB.COMPARE function to compare the CLOB columns.**

If this query returns any rows, the CLOBs are different (more or less characters, newlines, etc) or one of the rows exists in only one of the instances.

```
--Create temporary table to store the text in
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE X.TEMP_TEXT_TABLE
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS
AS
   SELECT * FROM X.TEXT_TABLE@REMOTE_DB;

--Use this statement if you need to refresh the TEMP_TEXT_TABLE table
INSERT INTO X.TEMP_TEXT_TABLE
SELECT * FROM X.TEXT_TABLE@REMOTE_DB;

--Do the comparision   
SELECT DISTINCT
       TARGET.NAME TARGET_NAME
      ,SOURCE.NAME SOURCE_NAME
      ,DBMS_LOB.COMPARE (TARGET.TEXT, SOURCE.TEXT) AS COMPARISON
  FROM    (SELECT ID, NAME, TEXT FROM X.TEMP_TEXT_TABLE) TARGET
       FULL OUTER JOIN
          (SELECT ID, NAME, TEXT FROM X.TEXT_TABLE) SOURCE
       ON TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID
 WHERE DBMS_LOB.COMPARE (TARGET.TEXT, SOURCE.TEXT) <> 0
    OR  DBMS_LOB.COMPARE (TARGETTEXT, SOURCE.TEXT) IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use DBMS_SQLHASH to compare the hashes of the relevant data.  This should use significantly less IO than moving and comparing the CLOBs.  The query below will just tell you if there are any differences in the entire table, but you can narrow it down.

```
select sys.dbms_sqlhash.gethash(sqltext => 'select text from text_table'
    ,digest_type => 1/*MD4*/) from dual
minus
select sys.dbms_sqlhash.gethash(sqltext => 'select text from text_table@remoteDB'
    ,digest_type => 1/*MD4*/) from dual;
```

Comment: I am not granted EXECUTE on the DMBS_SQLHASH package, but kudos for efficiency!